# Deploy individual Cloud Function for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to be able to deploy an individual Cloud Function for Firebase so I don't have to deploy my entire project every time.

There isn't an option through the CLI, but if there's a rest API or some other interface that Google or Firebase exposes to make this easier, that would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The CLI provides the capability to deploy a single function:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myFunction
```

or list of functions:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myFuncA,functions:myFuncB,functions:myFuncC
```

For more details:

```
firebase deploy --help
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I found the code in `firebase-tools` that I thought would do that but didn't find it documented anyplace. I might need to update my firebase-tools because `firebase deploy --help` mentions top level targets like "hosting,storage".

Comment: I recently upgraded to version 3.9.0.  `firebase -V` shows the version number.

Comment: upgrading to 3.9.0 shows more information and allows deploying one at a time, thanks!