# Sending chat Notifications in one to one chat using Firebase Cloud Function but in two different apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have made a one to one chat feature in my app in which user can send messages but the thing is chat is happening between doctor and patient so there is different app for doctor and different app for patient and both the apps are sharing the same database in Firebase.

So what I have done I have written a cloud function in patient app to send 
push notification when the new message is sent to the Doctor app.

```
//sends notification from patient app to Therapist
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/conversation/{conversationId}/messages/{messageId}').onWrite(event =>{
    const snapshot = event.data;

    if(snapshot.previous.val()){
        return;
    }
    var user_col = admin.database().ref('/users')
    //Notification details

     const message_text = snapshot.val().message;
     const sender_name = snapshot.val().name;
     const receive_therapist_uid = snapshot.val().receive_therapist;
     const receive_support_uid = snapshot.val().receive_support;
     const sender_uid = snapshot.val().sender;
     const attachmentType = snapshot.val().attachmentType;
     const timewrite  = snapshot.val().timewrite;
     const conversation_Id = snapshot.val().conversation_id;

     //therapist_id , therapist_name, therapist_email


     const payload = {
        data:{
            title: sender_name,
            username:sender_name,
            iduser:sender_uid,
            message:message_text ? (message_text.length <= 100 ? message_text : message_text.substring(0, 97) + '...') : 'sent a photo',
            conversation_id:conversation_Id
            }

     };



//send notification to therapist
          user_col.child(receive_therapist_uid).child('Fcm_id').once("value",function(dataSnapshot)
              {
                 const receive_therapist_fcm_id = dataSnapshot.val();

                 if(receive_therapist_fcm_id != null){

                 return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receive_therapist_fcm_id,payload).then(response => {

                     const tokensToRemove = [];
                     response.results.forEach((result) =>{
                         const error = result.error;

                         if(error){
                             console.error('Failure sending notification to',receive_therapist_fcm_id, error);
                            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
                            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                                            error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered'){

                                                 tokensToRemove.push(receive_therapist_fcm_id).remove();


                            }
                         }
                     });

                      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);

                 });
             }
          });
        });
```

But the problem is there  are many functions other than this send Notification function in the Patient app so when I am deploying the send Notification function in the Doctor app my other cloud functions of the patients are deleted. I know why this is happening because these both apps are sharing the same database so is there any way so that I do not loose my other cloud functions in the patient app and I can successfully deploy my send Notifications cloud function in the Doctor app.

Comment: `firebase deploy --only functions:myFunction` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120935/deploy-individual-cloud-function-for-firebase

Comment: Sorry for asking this question and thanks I am new to cloud functions

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen